# Homework for Gauss Seidel method

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let A be a strictly diagonally dominant matrix.
Suppose we use Gauss Seidel method to solve $Ax=b$, a sequence of vectors {$x_{0},x_{1},...,x_{k},...$} is obtained (where $x_{0}$ is the initial guess)
Let $x^{*}$ is the solution.
Show that $C_{1} \|x_{k}-x^{*}\|_{\infty} \leq \|x_{k}-x_{k-1}\|_{\infty}\leq C_{2} \|x_{k}-x^{*}\|_{\infty}$ for some positive constant $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$.

I prove the former inequality by showing $\|x_{k}-x^{*}\|_{\infty} \leq \|A^{-1}U\|\|x_{k}-x_{k-1}\|_{\infty}$
where $U$ is the upper triangular part of $A$.(not include the diagonal)
Actually, I have show that $A(x_{k}-x^{*})=U(x_{k}-x_{k-1})$.
But I don't know how to show the later inequality since I don't know if $U$ is invertible.

Comment: Would you describe the formulation of the Gauss Seidel method then I can probably help.

Comment: should the latter inequality have $x_{k-1}$?

Comment: The iterative scheme of Gauss Seidel method is : $(L+D)x_{k+1}+Ux_{k}=b$ where$L$, $D$ and $U$ are the lower triangular part (not include the diagonal), diagonal and upper triangular part (not include the diagonal) of $A$ resp.

Comment: and should the latter inequality have $x_{k-1}$ rather than $x_k$?

Comment: No,the question is $\|x_{k}-x_{k-1}\|_{\infty}\leq C_{2} \|x_{k}-x^{*}\|_{\infty}$. But I don't know if it is a typo.

Comment: okay, I'll work on it.

Comment: ellya, you right, it is $x_{k-1}$

Comment: Okay that's good, does my answer suffice?

Answer (score 1):

Another way of writing gauss seidel is:

$x_{k+1}=(D+L)^{-1}(D+L-A)x_k+(D+L)^{-1}b$, thus

$x_{k+1}-x_{k}=-(D+L)^{-1}Ax_k+(D+L)^{-1}Ax^*=(D+L)^{-1}A(x^*-x_k)$, so:

$\|x_{k+1}-x_{k}\|\leq\|(D+L)^{-1}\|\|A\|\|x^*-x_k\|$

Also as $A$ is strictly diagonaally dominant, is diagonal entries are non zero, so the determinant of (D+L) is the product of all the diagonal entries of $A$, which is non zero so (D+L) is invertible.